# Configuration properties in Android

Tags: android

I want to store some configuration in my app (like the URLs to my web services), similar to a config.properties for Tomcat or Jetty.

It seems that I have to use SharedPreferences, 2 problems:

1. If I want to use PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context) what should be the file name and where should it be in the project?
2. I tried getSharedPreferences("config.properties", MODE_PRIVATE) after creating config.properties in the assets folder but that doesn't work, what is the correct way to do? The file contains pairs like key=value.

Also what is the most secure way to save sensitive config values such as credentials (like AWS keys)?

If someone form Google is reading me, your doc is pretty vague/non-existant (or hard to find) about that stuff.

Thanks

Comment: do you think about rooted devices?

Comment: It's why I am asking if there is some way I may not have heard about yet ;-)

Answer (score 0):

1/2)You don't pre-store shared preferences.  They exist on disk only (not in the apk).  If you need them to exist in the apk, use a different file format (like json) and transfer them to shared preferences the first time you're run.

3)The best way to store sensitive data is off-device on a server and transferred only when needed via an HTTPS web service.  Anything else can be trivially found by anyone with any knowledge of reverse engineering.

Comment: Do you mean the app should call some web service the first time it is run to grab the config?

Comment: No, for the config data unless its sensitive it can be kept in a file in the apk, and then you parse and transfer it to shared preference the first time you launch.  But for anything sensitive, like encryption keys or login data to web services, you shouldn't have it anywhere in the apk or on disk or it will be easily read by attackers.  It should be downloaded every time the app is run and not stored on device.